# как решить данную задачу, в голову приходит только решение с массивами

Tags: php

1.Дана строка с повторными словами:
«Я люблю море. Я лечу на море. Я умею плавать в море. Какое чистое море! Хочу на море. Завтра поедем на море.»

2.Присвойте указанную фразу в виде значения переменной.
Найдите в ней повторяющееся слово и присвойте его в виде строки в другую переменную.

3.Замените повторные слова в указанной фразе на те же самые (с помощью функции для замены подстрок в строках), перевёрнутые в обратном порядке с помощью функции strrev.

Условие: в функции замены подстрок нужно использовать созданные переменные.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: 1) разбить строку на слова 2) подсчитать сколько раз каждое слово используется 3) отфильтровать использование более 1 раза 3) провести замену

Comment: в рамках данной задачи, наверное,  подстроками можно пренебречь.  Обратите внимание, что задача, навереное стара как мир, и функция `strrev` в современном мире не работает с русским текстом.

Comment: @teran Так задание требует не реверса слова. а именно применения функции... ну, может, чтобы студенты на собственном опыте познали эту некорректность?

Comment: @teran помогите, я совсем не понимаю как можно это реализовать все, хоть на примере чего-то

Answer (score -1):

Вряд ли у вас задачу примут в таком виде, но вот шаги, которые надо сделать:

> 1. разбить строку на слова 2) подсчитать сколько раз каждое слово используется 3) отфильтровать использование более 1 раза 3) провести замену

и в терминах пхп:

```
$text = "hello hello mad mad mad world";

$replace = array_keys(array_filter(
              array_count_values(explode(' ', $text)), fn($v) => $v > 1
           ));
$result = str_replace($replace, array_map('strrev', $replace), $text));
```

для успешной сдачи, мне кажется, все присутствующие функции языка придется переписать вручную.